# Just installed Ubuntu server - What services can i disable/uninstall?

Tags: ubuntu, service, uninstall, cleanup

i just installed Ubuntu server 13.04.
What services can i disable/uninstall? All i want is to keep sshd (to connect to my vps) and whatever is absolutely needed for the system to run and get rid of the rest. So far i have only uninstalled apache.

I want a minimal system to start from there and install only what i need.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      20   0 26492 2304 1388 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.14 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/108
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/108
   65 root      20   0 15220  636  420 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 upstart-file-br
   77 root      20   0 17268  820  608 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 upstart-udev-br
   94 root      20   0 21476 1292  736 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd
  160 messageb  20   0 23804  940  648 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.01 dbus-daemon
  256 root      20   0 21472  904  336 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd
  257 root      20   0 21472  900  336 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd
  278 root      20   0 15208  624  424 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 upstart-socket-
  398 root      20   0 14968 1072  888 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
  403 root      20   0 21276 1040  800 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 cron
  431 syslog    20   0 12748  840  656 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 syslogd
  460 root      20   0 52204 2744 2148 S   0.0  0.3   0:00.00 sshd
  491 root      20   0 80868 1084  396 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 saslauthd
  492 root      20   0 80868  736   48 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 saslauthd
  637 root      20   0 85620 2252  572 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.01 sendmail-mta
  910 root      20   0 75612 3620 2772 S   0.0  0.3   0:00.11 sshd
  922 root      20   0 18072 2040 1552 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.02 bash
 3235 root      20   0 17620 1408 1028 R   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
```

Thanks!

Comment: All the processes do a job. Only you know if you need that job to be done. I get the feeling you just want someone to give you a laundry list of things to disable, pat you on your head, and send you on your way but the real answer is to spend some time understanding what different 'services' do and make your own intelligent decision based on your requirements.

Comment: I think i explained pretty good what i want. I want a minimal install. No webserver no mail server etc. And all i wanted is for someone to help me uninstall what i don't need without breaking something. Keep only the necessary for the system to run and be able to login via ssh. And the guy below did just that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is always a good start:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/five-minutes-to-a-secure-linux-system.html

You could probably also disable sendmail-mta and saslauthd in you aren't running a mailserver and don't care for system emailing you critical alerts.

-- ab1

Comment: [Answers that are little more than a link to another site are not very useful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Good point, however sometimes link to another site is the most effective way to demonstrate a general solution to a commodity problem (rather than transcribing), such as in this case.

Comment: then you misunderstand serverfault, indeed the whole of stack exchange. It's supposed to be a repository for knowledge in itself, not simply links to to other places where that knowledge is now, and where those other sites might go offline or otherwise change what you're trying to say with the link. A paraphrased or quoted extract along with the link is really what's expected for a quality answer.